# iPhone SDK: iTunes Artwork Not Showing

Tags: iphone

My problem is that I don't see a icon when I look for my app in iTunes. I am not sure why?
I am creating IPA files. I include an image called iTunesArtwork.png.

Any help appreciated.

This is what i am seeing in iTunes. Notice no image for iCreditCard.
Why can't I see my icon? (See iCreditCard app with empty image)
[image]

This is the contents of the IPA folder.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I put iTunesArtwork (a jpeg file with no file extension/suffix) inside my Ad Hoc ipa files, not iTunesArtwork.png.

Comment: This is correct. The iTunesArtwork file should not include the .png extension. Strange, but true.